# python np.c_ error"CClass object is not callabel"

Tags: python, numpy

I'm using ipython 4.0.1 and python 3.5.1, when I call np.c_(), it shows an error

```
CClass object is not callable.
```

This is my code:

```
import numpy as np


rows = []
with open('ntumlone.dat') as f:
    rows = [list(map(float, L.split())) for L in f]

arr = np.array(rows)

date = np.c_(np.ones(len(arr)), arr)
```

What's wrong with me?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Try

```
date = np.c_[np.ones(len(arr)), arr]
```

Check its docs. You 'call' it with square brackets, as though you are indexing, not with `()`.  If the distinction is too confusing stick with `concatenate` or one of the `stack` functions.  I think in this use it is the same as `vstack`.

Comment: what is the difference between using 'c_[]'/'r_[]' vs 'hstack()' and 'vstack()'?